# max amperage of WAGO 222-415 connector?

Tags: power, amperage, power-engineering

Here's a really nice multi-wire splicing connector:

http://www.wago.us/news/5019.htm

http://www.wago.us/images/222415_PR.jpg

I'm using it for power distribution for a quadcopter:

http://eastbay-rc.blogspot.com/2011/03/update-wago-connector-for-power.html

[image]

The specs say it has a listed capacity of 600V/20A.  If I am using it for 12V apps, can I go higher on the amperage?  i.e., are these rating in terms of total current flow?

Comment: 600V is the marketing spec, you need to go to the datasheet where it says 400V continuous or 4kV burst.

Comment: 20Ampere at 600Volts is 1.2 Kilowatts. So at 12Volts you can put 1000Amps through it.. but you will need a massive core cable to handle that. Thats why Electricity is transported at High Voltage to keep the size of the core small. Ohms Law..

Comment: @ppumkin - the 600V is the isolation between adjacent contacts. There's no current flow between them. A contact will have millīohm resistance.

Comment: @stevenh - not sure what you mean? that is a connection block. So you mean exceeding 600volt on the block it could arc to the the nearest leakage point? why would it rate the adjacent contacts, if they are all connected and the shortest distance is the copper core rail inside the block- surely arc'ing would not occur then?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you're hoping that the capacity is a function of power, so that by decreasing the voltage you can increase the current.  Unfortunately, that's not the case.

Voltage maximums for connectors are generally a function of the insulating characteristics of the materials.  If you exceed 600V for this connector, you may get arcing or the insulation may break down.

Current maximums are due to the resistance of the connector and wire used for insertion.  These connectors don't give a resistance rating, but 20A will generate a lot of heat in the 28AWG wire these things are rated for, and you could exceed the maximum temperature of \$85^{o}\mbox{ }C\$.  This power dissipation is not due to the voltage present on the wires, but the voltage across the resistance inherent in the connections, so it doesn't matter whether you're using 600V or 12V.

Also, unless it says otherwise, these are generally static ratings: You need to plug everything in before you turn the power on, and turn the power off before you unplug anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any other information, I'd limit it to 20A.

Comment: Using Ohms law you can calculate the upper limit. based on Voltage and Amps. 20A is the Max at 600Volt - For the very reason that @Kevin stated- for Arching, melting, heat, etc. At 12 Volt you can go pretty high with low danger.